# function in javascript doesn't work once being trigger?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a vanilla javascript calculator from scratch. I was able to accomplish the separation between the numbers and operations but once I pass the arrays to another functions that function doesn't work at all for some reason. Please note I'm a self-learner and I'm a beginner javascript developer so I'm in the process to learn and practice. The code:

```js
//Index.js where the problem is
// this the field to control the result textfield
var textfield = " ";

//this function to copy the number/operations button to the textfiled
//it works
function retunNumber(val) {
    console.log(val);
    if (textfield != " ") {
        textfield = textfield + val;
        document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;
    } else if (textfield == " ") {
        textfield = val;
        document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;
    }
}

//this function to clear the textfield
//it works
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('result').value= " ";
    textfield = " ";
});



// This the functions where the calculation spouses to //happen but 
//nothing
//not sure
function result(numbers, operations){

    var currentResult = numbers[0];
    for(var i =0; i<= operations.length ; i++){
        if(operations[i] == '+'){
            currentResult = currentResult + numbers[i+1];
        }else if(operations[i] == '-'){
            currentResult = currentResult - numbers[i+1];
        }else if(operations[i] == '*'){
            currentResult = currentResult * numbers[i+1];
        }if(operations[i] == '/'){
            currentResult = currentResult / numbers[i+1];
        }else{
            currentResult = "Wrong";
        } 
    }return currentResult;
}

//this the function where it should give the result
// it works partially, only in the separation of the number and the 
//operation but not in returning the result
document.getElementById('equal').addEventListener("click", function(){

    var numbers = textfield.split(/\D/g);
    var operations = textfield.split(/\d/g).filter(Boolean);
    
    /*
    console.log(textfield);
    console.log(numbers);
    console.log(operations);
    */
//here is where it spouses to return the result but nothing
   if(Number.isInteger(result(numbers, operations)) == true){
    textfield =result(numbers, operations);
   }else{
       textfield = "Invalid expression"
   }
    


});
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container {
    margin: 10%;

}

.item1 {
grid-column: 1/5;
}

.item2 {
    grid-column: 2/4;
}

.item3 {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 4;
}

.item4 {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 4;
}
.item5 {
    grid-row: 4;
    grid-column: 4;
}

.textField {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="grid-container">

            <div class="item1"> <input type="text" name="result" id="result" class="textField"> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="1">1</button> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="2">2</button> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="3">3</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="4">4</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="5">5</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="6">6</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="7">7</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="8">8</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="9">9</button></div>
            <div class="item2"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="0">0</button></div>
            <div class="item5"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="*">*</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="/">/</button></div>
            <div class="item3"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="+">+</button></div>
            <div class="item4"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="-">-</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="equal">Equal</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Delete</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="clear">Clear</button></div>


        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: This condition: `i<= operations.length` should be `i< operations.length`

Comment: This; `} else if (textfield == " ") {` can just be an `} else {`, since you know at that point that the `textfied` does equal `" "`.

Comment: @ziggywiggy I changed nothing the same :( now I'll try the next comment

Comment: What happens with `textfield`? It is just a string but is it supposed to display somewhere on the page?

Comment: This: `}if(operations[i] == '/'){` should be `} else if(operations[i] == '/'){`, otherwise the next `else` will wipe out whatever condition above may have been met

Comment: @AndyG the textfield is the input text on the html file

Comment: Here's how I'd write your `result` function (just a preference): `function result(numbers, operations) {
  return operations.reduce((res, op, i) =>
    op == '+' ? res + numbers[i + 1] :
    op == '-' ? res - numbers[i + 1] :
    op == '*' ? res * numbers[i + 1] :
    op == '/' ? res / numbers[i + 1] : NaN, numbers[0])
}`

Comment: @ziggywiggy seems interesting but first I'm trying to get familiar with the original syntax them I'll try the new syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple small issues.

1. `}if(operations[i] == '/'){` needs to be `}else if(operations[i] == '/'){` add the `else`
2. `for(var i =0; i<= operations.length ; i++){` needs to be `for(var i =0; i< operations.length ; i++){` Remove the `=`
3. You are assigning to `textfield` so when you hit `equal` again, the `textfield` is no longer the value you think it is. You need to assign `textField` to the textbox on the page.
4. Inside of the `result` function, `currentResult` and `numbers[i+1]` are treated as a `string` type. You need to use `parseInt` to convert these to an integer.
5. `Number.isInteger` will always return false in this situation because the the function `result` has a return type of `string`. You need to convert it back to a number by adding `+` in front of the function call.

```js
   //Index.js where the problem is
var textfield = " ";

function retunNumber(val) {
    console.log(val);
    if (textfield != " ") {
        textfield = textfield + val;
        document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;
    } else if (textfield == " ") {
        textfield = val;
        document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;
    }
}

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('result').value= " ";
    textfield = " ";
});



// This the functions where the calculation spouses to //happen but nothing
function result(numbers, operations){

    var currentResult = parseInt(numbers[0]);
    for(var i =0; i < operations.length ; i++){
        if(operations[i] == '+'){
            currentResult = currentResult + parseInt(numbers[i+1]);
        }else if(operations[i] == '-'){
            currentResult = currentResult - parseInt(numbers[i+1]);
        }else if(operations[i] == '*'){
            currentResult = currentResult * parseInt(numbers[i+1]);
        }else if(operations[i] == '/'){
            currentResult = currentResult / parseInt(numbers[i+1]);
        }else{
            currentResult = "Wrong";
        } 
    }return currentResult;
}

document.getElementById('equal').addEventListener("click", function(){

    var numbers = textfield.split(/\D/g);
    var operations = textfield.split(/\d/g).filter(Boolean);
    
    /*
    console.log(textfield);
    console.log(numbers);
    console.log(operations);
    */
   if(Number.isInteger(+result(numbers, operations)) == true){
    textfield =result(numbers, operations);
   }else{
       textfield = "Invalid expression"
   }
   document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;


});
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container {
    margin: 10%;

}

.item1 {
grid-column: 1/5;
}

.item2 {
    grid-column: 2/4;
}

.item3 {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 4;
}

.item4 {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 4;
}
.item5 {
    grid-row: 4;
    grid-column: 4;
}

.textField {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="grid-container">

            <div class="item1"> <input type="text" name="result" id="result" class="textField"> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="1">1</button> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="2">2</button> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="3">3</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="4">4</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="5">5</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="6">6</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="7">7</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="8">8</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="9">9</button></div>
            <div class="item2"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="0">0</button></div>
            <div class="item5"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="*">*</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="/">/</button></div>
            <div class="item3"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="+">+</button></div>
            <div class="item4"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="-">-</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="equal">Equal</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Delete</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="clear">Clear</button></div>


        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Good explanation. but there is small issue in point 4. This is calculator so result is supposed to return integer. Problem lies while calculation. numbers[0] and numbers[i+1]  shall be parsed to Int while calculation in result function.

Comment: it works but fully the addition and division doesn't work.

Comment: @AbdallahRizk, I do not understand what you mean bu the addition and division doesn't work..

Comment: when I run the snippet code the addition give me a strange result, eg: 2+3=23 and in the division eg, 2/3= Invalid expression

Comment: @AbdallahRizk `2+3=23` this is because you add two string. Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @S.Walker *You need to convert it back to a number by adding + in front of the function call.* You need to parse into integer the calculated value too. Like `currentResult = parseInt(currentResult) + parseInt(numbers[i+1]);`

Comment: @S.Walker please edit your answer so everyone would get the benefit

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a value to `textfield` but this is just a string, it won't automatically appear in the page.

If you want its value to appear in the page (when pressing 'equals') then you would use:

```
document.getElementById('result').value = "some value";
```

---

Note that you are also calling your function `result(numbers, operations)` twice, it is better to call it once and store the result.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

You can change your event equal like

```
document.getElementById('equal').addEventListener("click", function(){
    var elResult = document.getElementById('result');
    textfield = " ";
    elResult.value = eval(elResult.value);
})
```

Or (better) you can use [window.Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```
document.getElementById('equal').addEventListener("click", function(){
  var elResult = document.getElementById('result');

  textfield = " ";
  elResult.value = Function('"use strict";return (' + elResult.value + ')')();
})
```

---

e.g.

```js
var newNum = true;

function retunNumber(val) {
  if (newNum) {
    document.getElementById('result').value = val;
    newNum = false
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').value += val;
  }
}

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('result').value = " ";
  newNum = true;
});

document.getElementById('equal').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var elResult = document.getElementById('result');

  newNum = true;
  elResult.value = Function('"use strict";return (' + elResult.value + ')')();
})
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container {
  margin: 10%;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.item4 {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.item5 {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.textField {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="grid-container">

      <div class="item1"> <input type="text" name="result" id="result" class="textField"> </div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="1">1</button> </div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="2">2</button> </div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="3">3</button></div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="4">4</button></div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="5">5</button></div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="6">6</button></div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="7">7</button></div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="8">8</button></div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="9">9</button></div>
      <div class="item2"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="0">0</button></div>
      <div class="item5"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="*">*</button></div>
      <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="/">/</button></div>
      <div class="item3"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="+">+</button></div>
      <div class="item4"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="-">-</button></div>
      <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="equal">Equal</button></div>
      <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Delete</button></div>
      <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="clear">Clear</button></div>


    </div>

  </div>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: your solution is innovative but the thing it makes me remove the issue and solve it in another way and I really wanna know what is the wrong in my methods current method but for sure I'll be looking for what is eval() and windows.function cause right now what I see is just magics

Answer (score 0):

The array of values is a string array, so you must convert every item for number, use `parseInt`.

```
/* here must be `else if` */

} if(operations[i] == '/'){ 
        currentResult = currentResult / numbers[i+1];
    }else{
        currentResult = "Wrong";
    }
```

OBS: float number will make errors.
Precedence ignored.

```js
//Index.js where the problem is
// this the field to control the result textfield
var textfield = " ";

//this function to copy the number/operations button to the textfiled
//it works
function retunNumber(val) {
    if (textfield != " ") {
        textfield = textfield + val;
        document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;
    } else if (textfield == " ") {
        textfield = val;
        document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;
    }
}

//this function to clear the textfield
//it works
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('result').value= " ";
    textfield = " ";
});



// This the functions where the calculation spouses to //happen but 
function result(numbers, operations){
    
    var currentResult = parseInt(numbers[0]); // first of all, convert to number
    
    for(var i = 0; i < operations.length ; i++) {
        // convert to number
        var currentNumber = parseInt(numbers[i+1]);
        
        if(operations[i] == '+') {
            currentResult +=  currentNumber
        } else if(operations[i] == '-') {
            currentResult -=  currentNumber
        } else if(operations[i] == '*') {
            currentResult *=  currentNumber
        } else if(operations[i] == '/') {
            currentResult /=  currentNumber
        } else {
            currentResult = "Wrong";
        }
    }
    return currentResult;
}

//this the function where it should give the result
// it works partially, only in the separation of the number and the 
//operation but not in returning the result
document.getElementById('equal').addEventListener("click", function(){

   var numbers = textfield.split(/\D/g);
   var operations = textfield.split(/\d/g).filter(Boolean);
    
   const res = result(numbers, operations)
   if( Number.isInteger(res) ) { /* == true <- redundant  ){ */
       textfield = res;
   } else {
       textfield = "Invalid expression"
   }

    /* set value to texfield */
    document.getElementById('result').value = textfield;

});
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container {
    margin: 10%;

}

.item1 {
grid-column: 1/5;
}

.item2 {
    grid-column: 2/4;
}

.item3 {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 4;
}

.item4 {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 4;
}
.item5 {
    grid-row: 4;
    grid-column: 4;
}

.textField {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="grid-container">

            <div class="item1"> <input type="text" name="result" id="result" class="textField"> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="1">1</button> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="2">2</button> </div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="3">3</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="4">4</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="5">5</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="6">6</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="7">7</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="8">8</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="9">9</button></div>
            <div class="item2"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="0">0</button></div>
            <div class="item5"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="*">*</button></div>
            <div> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="/">/</button></div>
            <div class="item3"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="+">+</button></div>
            <div class="item4"> <button onclick="retunNumber(this.value)" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="-">-</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="equal">Equal</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Delete</button></div>
            <div> <button class="btn btn-outline-info" id="clear">Clear</button></div>


        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```